# Angular Material design chips not working

Tags: angular, material-design, angular5

I'm building a simple app that would render some chips using material 2 but nothing is working at my end, here is the same code:
Component- (Note - I'm calling this component inside app component but still nothing is rendering)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import {ENTER, COMMA} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-chip-list',
  templateUrl: './mat-chip-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-chip-list.component.css']
})
export class MatChipListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

HTMl File-

```
 <mat-chip-list>
      <mat-chip>One fish</mat-chip>
      <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
      <mat-chip color="primary" selected="true">Primary fish</mat-chip>
      <mat-chip color="accent" selected="true">Accent fish</mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
```

App Module- (I need to implement the chips using input that would filter out the data from the ag grid. But currently nothing is rendering.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderContentComponent } from './header-content/header-content.component';
import { PageNavigationComponent } from './page-navigation/page-navigation.component';
import { FundsFilterSectionComponent } from './funds-filter-section/funds-filter-section.component';
import { DistributionAnalyzedReturnComponent } from './distribution-analyzed-return/distribution-analyzed-return.component';
import { FundsTableComponent } from './funds-table/funds-table.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms"; // <-- NgModel lives here
// HttpClient
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { MatChipListComponent } from './mat-chip-list/mat-chip-list.component';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';

import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  .....
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  .....
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule
  ]
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderContentComponent,
    PageNavigationComponent,
    FundsFilterSectionComponent,
    DistributionAnalyzedReturnComponent,
    FundsTableComponent,
    MatChipListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  BrowserAnimationsModule,  FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can you let me know what mistake am I making in my code, I've tried following the exact guide as on material.angular.io but its still not displaying anything.

Comment: @Florentine any idea on this?

Comment: Did you import the `MatChipsModule` ?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @ibenjelloun yes I started from AutoComplete and went till tooltipModule. Also, here is the error on console
 Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
    at eval (core.js:5494)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at NgZone.run (core.js:4566)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:5489)
    at eval (core.js:5568)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)

Comment: @bugs - here is the warning I'm getting on console- 
Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included? at eval (core.js:5494) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388) at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387) at Zone.run (zone.js:138) at NgZone.run (core.js:4566) at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:5489) at eval (core.js:5568) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388) at Zone.run (zone.js:138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from the fact that you define `@NgModule` twice. Remove the first one:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  .....
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule
  ]
})
```

Comment: Any idea if we want to club the input from angular chips with quick filter? eg this code- 
 <div class="search-box"  *ngIf="gridApi"><p>Search</p><span class="search-button"><label>Search funds:</label></span>
    <input class="search-input"  [ngModel]="filterText" (ngModelChange)="gridApi.setQuickFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter Table..."/>
  </div> 
This is for the normal quick filter input